# XCUITest ProgressView identifier hardcoded to "In progress" when within a Button

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcuitest

When creating a `ProgressView` and using `.accessibilityIdentifier` or a standard label, UI tests are able identify it.

The view:

```swift
ProgressView().accessibilityIdentifier("Test")
```

The following assertion passes:

```swift
XCTAssert(app.activityIndicators["Test"].exists)
```

When placing this `ProgressView` within a `Button` however, UI tests fail to identify it.

The view:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    ProgressView().accessibilityIdentifier("Test")
}
```

The same assertion fails:

```swift
XCTAssert(app.activityIndicators["Test"].exists)
```

Interestingly, one can use "In progress" to identify the `ProgressView` within a `Button`, but what about when I have multiple?

```swift
XCTAssert(app.activityIndicators["In progress"].exists)
```

Why is this `ProgressView` not identifiable within a `Button` via it's `accessibilityIdentifier`?

Bonus question, why is this available under `app.activityIndicators` but not `app.progressIndicators` as one might expect?

- Xcode 13.3.1
- iOS 15.4

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that when your ProgressView is placed inside the button it probably becomes of type 'otherElement' and this is the reason you are unable to find it using 'app.activityIndicators'. I would suggest you print out your app elements hierarchy using:

```
print(app.debugDescription)
```

or while debugging using the lldb:

```
po app
```

and check the actual type of the element and how it fits in the hierarchy. Or you could directly test it out using:

```
app.otherElements["Test"].exists
```

Edit:
I did not understand the initial problem so I am adding to the answer about your question for multiple existing indicators. In this case you might want to avoid using `app.activityIndicators` and improve your queries like this:

1. Using a specific button element to get the needed indicator:

```
let button = app.buttons["test"]
let indicator = button.activityIndicators.element(boundBy: 0)
```

2. Using XCUIElementQuery:

```
let buttons = app.buttons.matching(identifier: "test")
let indicator = buttons.element(boundBy: 0).activityIndicators.element(boundBy: 0)
```

With these you don't even have to use the activityIndicator accessibilityIdentifier.

Comment: Thanks for your response Cheetah! You'll notice that I mention that the `ProgressView` *is* available under `app.activityIndicators`, but that its label (ie. identifier) is "In progress" when it is placed within a `Button`. The `ProgressView` does not appear in `app.otherElements` and so your assertion fails unfortunately.

Comment: Also thanks to your response, I updated the question title to be hopefully a little clearer.

Comment: I am so sorry for misunderstanding, mate, updated the answer